# Counting every part of polygons inside another polygon feature class in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, overlapping-features, count

I have two polygon feature classes. The first one represents lithostratygraphy distribution. The second one is an artificial grid polygon feature class.

I want to count the absolute number of patches of the lithostratygraphy (not polygons) inside the each mesh of the grid feature class.

1. I use the `Intersect tool` to divide the classes in the grids.
2. Using the `Joins and Relates > Join tool`, I calculate the number of polygons in successive meshes.

The problem concerns parts of the patches belonging to the same polygon (e.g. purple upper and lower patches). I would like them to be treated separately, i.e. the result written in the `_Counts` attribute would be 4, not 3.

[image]

How do I split polygons by geometry or how to generate new general geometry feature class like in GeoMedia?

Comment: The left square should get count 4, and the right 2? Try multipart to singlepart after Intersect to split the pink polygon

Comment: Initially _Count attribute of the left square was 5 and the right square was 3 because the north and south patches of the right square were parts of the same violet poligon. 
As you suggested, I intersected the litostr. class by the grid feature class, and then I split parts of the poligons by the Multipart To Single part tool. The polygons inside the grid boxes have been separated.
Unfortunately, after Joins and Relates > Join to count number of litostr. patches inside the squares, the value of the _Count attribute of the right square was 16! It is wrong. It should be 4. Where is a problem?